# trouble reading from textbox in c# from to win32 C++ program?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to read from the C# form that i created and pass it on my win 32 application. The trouble is i always get a null wstring instead of getting the text from the textbox.i create a refrence to the C# form dll file from my c++ program. I know the trouble is in the C# part as i debugged through it and found that it itself never gets the value from  the text.
Since its my first time using C# i dont know what is wrong i am pasting my C# code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UpdaterForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text=textBox1.Text;
        }

        public String textbox1
        {
            get{
                  return textBox1.Text;
            }
        }


        public String textbox2
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox2.Text;
            }
        }

        public String textbox3
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox3.Text;
            }
        }

    }
}





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UpdaterForm
{
    public class UpdaterForm
    {
        public string PickText( )
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            String text1;
            String text2;
            String text3;

            Application.Run(form);
            text1 = form.textbox1;
            text2 = form.textbox2;
            text3 = form.textbox3;
            form.Dispose();
            string text = text1 + "." + text2 + "." + text3;
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the c++ code

```
#include <string>

class UpdaterFormClient
{
 private:

    void* ref;

    void alloc();
    void free();
    wchar_t * pick();

 public:

    UpdaterFormClient();
    ~UpdaterFormClient();

    void picker(std::wstring &);
};
```

the cpp file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "UpdaterFormClient.h"
#include <vcclr.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

#pragma unmanaged

UpdaterFormClient::UpdaterFormClient()
{
 alloc();
}

UpdaterFormClient::~UpdaterFormClient()
{
 free();
}

void UpdaterFormClient::picker(std::wstring &text1)
{
 wchar_t *p;

 p = pick();
 text1 = p;
 delete [] p;
}

#pragma managed
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <..\\..\\UpdaterForm\\UpdaterForm\\bin\\debug\\UpdaterForm.dll>

void UpdaterFormClient::alloc()
{
 GCHandle gch;
 UpdaterForm::UpdaterForm ^obj;

 obj = gcnew UpdaterForm::UpdaterForm();
 gch = GCHandle::Alloc(obj);
 ref = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(gch).ToPointer();

 return;
}

void UpdaterFormClient::free()
{
 IntPtr temp(ref);
 GCHandle gch;

 gch = static_cast<GCHandle>(temp);
 gch.Free();
}

wchar_t * UpdaterFormClient::pick()
{
 IntPtr temp(ref);
 String ^text1;
 wchar_t *ret;
 GCHandle gch;
 UpdaterForm::UpdaterForm ^obj;

 gch = static_cast<GCHandle>(temp);
 obj = static_cast<UpdaterForm::UpdaterForm ^>(gch.Target);
 text1 = obj->PickText();
 ret = new wchar_t[text1->Length + 1];

 interior_ptr<const wchar_t> p1 = PtrToStringChars(text1);
 pin_ptr<const wchar_t> p2 = p1;
 wcscpy_s(ret, text1->Length + 1, p2);

 return ret;
}
```

Comment: What about your C++ code? How are you trying to retrieve the textbox string?

Comment: Hard to see what the problem is? Why do we have to wade through acres of empty methods?

Comment: i added the c++ code , sorry for the methods i just pasted the code what i got when i made the gui

Answer (score 0):

Windows programs don't work as you expect.

You start an Application Loop `Application.Run(form)` and then, when that ends, you try to get the textbox values.

You can't do this in a Windows program.

`Application.Run(form)` will block until the window closes or the message loop ends.

Therefore, you need to move the code dealing with your textboxes into your form.

Place a button on your form, and put the textbox code into the button click event.  Use a MessageBox.Show call to display what was entered.

I've attempted to demonstrate this here (you will need to explain the c++ part in more depth):

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace UpdaterForm 
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

        } 

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

        } 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            String text1 = textBox1.Text;  
            String text2 = textBox2.Text;  
            String text3 = textBox3.Text;  
            string text = text1 + "." + text2 + "." + text3; 
            MessageBox.Show(text);           
        } 
    } 
} 

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 

using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace UpdaterForm 
{ 
    public class UpdaterForm 
    { 
        public string PickText( ) 
        { 
            Form1 form = new Form1(); 

            try {
              Application.Run(form); 
            } finally {
              form.Dispose();
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: so in my C++ code u will see it calls the PickText() method of c# text1 = obj->PickText(); which was public and contained all code for retrieving all the text. Since you moved it to the button click method can we pass the text variable to the PickText method. If we can i am pretty sure it would solve the problem